# Organic groups api?

Tags: organic-groups

I have the Organic Groups module working in my site, but when I try to use a simple function like [og_load()](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/og/og--og.module/function/og_load/7.x) in my module, I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function `og_load()`.

What should I do to use these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[og_load()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_load/7) is defined on the module file, which means it should be available once the module is enabled. Be sure to call the function when Drupal completed its bootstrap, and loaded all the enabled modules. If you call it inside [hook_boot()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_boot/7), or [hook_exit()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_exit/7), the function could not be available, if Drupal didn't complete its bootstrap.

Sometimes it's enough to increase the weight of the module calling `og_load()` to avoid the error (if the function is not called in the hooks I previously described). Execute the following code in `hook_install()`. (Replace mymodule with the short name of your module.)

```
$weight = db_query("SELECT weight from {system} WHERE name = 'og' AND type = 'module'")->fetchField();
db_update('system')
  ->fields(array('weight' => $weight + 1))
  ->condition('type', 'module')
  ->condition('name', 'mymodule')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Well, the module is enabled, and working, and I'm trying to call the function in a simple [hook_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). I don't quite get how the weight would affect the access to the functions, but i'll check it up thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function is undefined within the scope of your module because your module doesn't know about the Organic Groups module. You have to invoke the Organic Groups module before you can call its functions. (This is the case when using any module's functions.)

Using module_exists() should do the trick. As a bonus, it'll also protect you from unforeseen errors if the Organic Groups module is ever missing or turned off on your site:

```
if (module_exists('og')) {
  // your og_load() code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for drupal 7, the api function no more exist, instead node_load($group_id) can be used.

[Check this issue link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1663242#comment-6169986).